# How to redirect HTTP request in Apache using ProxyPass

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, centos7

I am working with OpenProject and pgAdmin.

While OpenProject configures itself entirely, I am albe to connect it from the "outside" using `http://ip-address/openproject`

I am trying to do the same for pgAdmin (which listens on 5050 port). So I did:

- in `config.py` file I switched `DEFUALT_SERVER = 0.0.0.0` as recommended in a file,
- in `pgadmin4.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` I wrote

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MY_IP_ADDRESS
    DocumentRoot /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/

    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
    WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25
    WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin4 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgAdmin4.wsgi

    ProxyRequests off

    ProxyPass /pgadmin/ http://127.0.0.1:5050/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse /pgadmin/ http://127.0.0.1:5050/
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

While I am able to connect from other local machine to pgAdmin with `http://my-ip-addres:5050/`, I am unable to connect it with `hhtp://my-ip-address/pgadmin`, I get reponse status code 404: page not found.

What am I doing wrong? All my trials are based on deep research of a web, but maybe I have missed something.

**EDIT**

As I discovered, all proxying is done in WSGI file, which uses `proxy_fix` package. Any ideas how to change that?

Comment: Please be more specific about the `unable to connect`. What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That the page is not found, I get response with status code 404.

Comment: Did you try `http://my-ip-address/pgadmin/` (with a trailing slash)? That's a difference.

Comment: btw, I'm not familiar with pgadmin, but from the documentation it looks like apache can be configured to connect to it either via ProxyPass or via WSGI. You configured both. You should not mix this, pick one and configure it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Could you exaplin/give some hints/give some sources on how WSGI and ProxyPass (not) work together?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It still gives me nothing... I tired to modify WSGI and dependant files, but no luck.